# LINQ to SQL relationships using compact edition

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, relational-database

I'm having a problem trying to use linq to sql to create a relationship between my two database entities. I've been following [this basic Microsoft guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic5) but without getting it to work.

I'm trying to store a tree-like structure. The ConfigUnit class contains information about a category of items and stores the tree name as well as the root node.

storeItem contains the information for each node in that tree.

```
[Table(Name = "ConfigUnit")]
public class ConfigUnit
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int cuID;

    ...

    private EntitySet<storeItem> _rootNode;
    [Association(Storage = "_rootNode", ThisKey = "cuID", OtherKey = "cuID")]
    public EntitySet<storeItem> rootNode
    {
        get
        {
            return _rootNode;
        }
        set
        {
            _rootNode = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And the storeItem class:

```
[Table(Name = "storeItem")]
public class storeItem
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int siID;

    [Column]
    public int cuID;

    private EntityRef<ConfigUnit> _CU;
    [Association(Storage = "_CU", ThisKey = "cuID")]
    public ConfigUnit ConfigUnit
    {
        get { return this._CU.Entity; }
        set { this._CU.Entity = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

However when I run the code and the database is created using DataContext.CreateDatabase() the relation does not seem to be created. The ConfigUnit table has no relationship column and no relationship values seem to be stored when I query the database afterwards.

What am I missing? I'm running a near-identical relationship as the linked Microsoft article.

Thanks for your time!

EDIT:
The generated SQL code is simply this:

```
 CREATE TABLE [ConfigUnit](
   [cuID] Int NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
   [topID] Int NOT NULL, 
   CONSTRAINT [PK_ConfigUnit] PRIMARY KEY ([cuID])
   )
```

Ie no relation is generated at all.
The only other related problem I could find was people who were missing primary keys on their entities, which I am not.

EDIT 2:
I tried using a full SQL server instead of a Compact edition one. Still the same result.

Comment: If you have an existing database, use my SQL CE Toolbox to create the code for you...

Comment: @ErikEJ Using the GUI to create a couple of test classes gave me the same problem with relations.